# How to Create Browser Toolbar in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i Want to create browser toolbar in asp.net as like google toolbar.

where user can download and make setup of toolbar and default search will be from our site

i.e. Gudipa.com for SEO

Answer (score 1):

You don't create browser toolbars in ASP.NET. You can create add-ons in Firefox, Chrome or IE - each has its own API. In Firefox and Chrome you write your add-on in Javascript. In IE you'd better use .NET (although maybe IE 10 has something different?)